# Free body diagram representation of coriolis force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, coriolis-effect

In many problems,horizontal and vertical components of coriolis force are taken into consideration. But I really don't know how to fit these components into a free body diagram. Can anyone help me out in drawing it?

Comment: Coriolis' force depends on velocity. When you know $\vec{v}$, you just draw the force and use basic trigonometry. What's the problem?

Comment: That part of our statement,"draw the force and use basic trigonometry" is what I don't know how to do?

Comment: Don't you know the right hand rule?

Comment: That's fine. But my question is about the direction of it's components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll ellaborate an example. Tell me where you have problems in the reasoning.

Given a latitude $\lambda$, you draw a radius $\vec{n}$, from the Earth's centre, making an angle $\lambda$ with the equator (E).

Then, draw the tangent plane. A plane tangent to the Earth at that point.

[image: Coriolis 1]

We also know that the angular velocity points upwards in the North Pole (N).

So, let's imagine that velocity points towards the North but parallel to the plane (light green). The cross products gives a Coriolis force pointing to the East. The Right hand rule gives a westerly direction, but the force has a minus sign, so it is easternly. I'll use "Ec" for the equator now.

[image: Corilois 2]

So, Coriolis force poitns to the east only. This is what we usually seek for, but you can also use trigonometry to split it into $x,y,z$. This is a trivial case.

Now, if velocity is tilted, for example, in angles $\alpha, \beta$, you proceed the same way, but now The Corilis force will form an angle with the normal vector. It is still perpendicular to both $\omega$ and $\\vec{v}$, but this time it also makes an angle with the normal. The angles are directly related to $\alpha, \beta$, the ones of velocity. You first know velocity, then you draw the rest.

[image: Coriolis 3]

Comment: Perfect explanation. My doubts got clarified. Initially I was so bad in drawing FBD but your representation using NEWS axis helped me in understanding the direction of coriolis force much better and you have also explained that negative sign shows opposite direction which is so helpful. Thanks for the timely help!

Comment: Oh really? I was in a hurry and I had to do this fast. I wanted to ellaborate the last example a little more, because it is harder to see, as vectors are tilted. I'm surprised (and glad) that this helped you.